# Use jQuery to bind to apex:apex:commandButton onComplete event

Tags: visualforce, javascript, jquery, commandbutton

Is it possible to bind to the `onComplete` event for an `<apex:commandButton/>`?

Instead of using the following format:

```
<script>
function myOnComplete(){
    // do onComplete stuff
}
</script>
<apex:commandButton action="{!myAction}" onComplete="myOnComplete();"/>
```

I would prefer to use jQuery to bind to the `onComplete` event, but have not had any luck:

```
<script>
var jQuery = $.noConflict(true);
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.myCmdButton').on('complete', function(){
        // do onComplete stuff
    });
});
</script>
<apex:commandButton action="{!myAction}" styleClass="myCmdButton" />
```

I've also tried to use the `ajaxComplete` event and then check the source as I have seen suggested, but this event doesn't seem to fire...

```
$(document).on('ajaxComplete', function(event, xhr, options){});
```

Comment: What are trying to accomplish? Could you brief your exact requirement? Here is the link to have jQuery ajax request: http://www.tgerm.com/2010/02/visualforce-salesforce-jquery-ajax-how.html

Comment: My apologies.... I am new to Salesforce stack exchange....

Comment: Can you explain a bit why you are preferring to use jQuery bindings? Knowing the end goal will help a lot in providing suggestions for new approaches.

Answer (score 1):

One possible work around I was able to find is to use a globally scoped function that is overridden within the `jQuery.ready()` section. Would like to see a better solution than this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// scope globally
var myOnComplete = function(){}

// Alias jQuery for noConflict
jQuery = $.noConflict(true);
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // redefine on jQuery.ready()
    myOnComplete = function(){
        var $doc = $(document);
        console.log('We can use jQuery $ here');
    }

}
</script>

<apex:commandButton 
    action="{!myAction}"
    value="My Action" 
    reRender="myTable" 
    id="myAction" 
    onComplete="myOnComplete();" />
```

Comment: If this question was answered by yourself, you should accept this answer. Otherwise, you could put a bounty on the question, asking for a better answer, but it may not be relevant now, seeing how old this question is.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
function myOnComplete(){
    // do onComplete stuff
}

</script>
<apex:commandButton action="{!myAction}" onComplete="myOnComplete();" />
```

Comment: Your example doesn't use jquery to bind to the event, you at using the onComplete attribute as in my example. I specifically need to know how to bind to `complete` using `jquery.on()`.

Comment: Oncomplete attribute IS javascript. It is a shortcut.

Comment: Can you write it using jquery.on() then?

Answer (score 0):

First give your button an ID which can be used in jquery. then access that button using jquery partial ID selector and bind it with the event you want.

```
$('.myCmdButton').on('complete', function(){ // do onComplete stuff });
```

try replacing above code with below one:

`jQuery( 'button[id$=yourId]' ).on('complete', function(){
//ur code.
}) ;`

Visit below link for more about partial ID selector inside VF. 
[Jquery in VF](http://www.kineticgrowth.com/javascript-visualforce-jquery-partial-id-selectors/)

mark it as correct and upvote if it helped.